# Gcd of polynomial in mod 7

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I am trying to find the gcd of

$$f(x)=x^{4}+5x+1$$ and $$g(x)=x^{2}-1$$ in $\mathbb{Z[x]}/7\mathbb{Z}$

To do such, I tried using Euclidian Algorithm, and first I divided f by g to get $x^{2}+1$ and a residue of $5x+2$

Then I divided $g$ by $5x+2$ to get $x^{2}-1$ and 0 residue

So if I didn't make mistakes with that, I thought my gcd will be $5x+2$ , normalized , ie $x+6$ in this field.

But that is not one of the choices

( The options are $x^{2}-1, x-1, 1$, or $x+1$)

So can someone please help to show me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $x-1 = x+6$ because we're working mod $7$.